# Power BI folder structure

Tags: powerbi

I'm considering migrating my data warehouse reporting from Cognos to Power BI.  We have several thousand reports in Cognos, stored in a folder structure that mimics the business structure.  If I were migrating to an on-prem SSRS instance, I would use the same folder structure.

As far as I can tell, I can't do that in Power BI regardless of whether I'm using dashboards or paginated (SSRS) reports.  I would have a "workspace" for the data warehouse alongside workspaces for other things (like applications, projects, offices, etc.).  I don't see a way to add folders within a workspace.  So I would need to put several thousand reports in one workspace.  (and I just read that there is a limit of 1000 data sets and reports in a workspace)

Am I just missing how to create a folder structure in Power BI or is that feature not available?

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently sub divide the workspaces down into folders in the Power BI Service. You would have to create workspaces that thematically arrange the reports.

If you have that many reports, I would consider looking at the usage, getting rid of any duplicates, not used, and similar reports and consolidate them were possible. I've been in migration projects from Congnos/Crystal/Qlik etc where all the reports were required to be transfered to Power BI, however after auditing them and the usage dropped over 75% of them.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, @Jon, but...  In May of this year I notified folks that I would start deleting the 13,000+ reports we have (of the 19,000+ total) that had not been used in over 28 months.  I got some big pushback.  I'm really happy for you that you were able to delete over 75% of your reports.